# Simple harmonic motion equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I don't really understand this equation and was wondering if someone could help.

The book says

> *when the restoring force is directly proportional to the displacement the oscillation is called [SHM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion).*

and this next part confuses me

> *the acceleration $a =d^2x/dt^2 = -kx/m$ so it makes sense since the second derivative of position is acc.*

but how do they get that last expression?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1018/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19588/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

For an ideal spring $F_{\text{spring}} = -kx.$

When a mass attached to a spring moves horizontaly, then:

$$F_{\text{total}}=F_{\text{spring}}=ma\Rightarrow -kx =ma \Rightarrow a=-\dfrac{k}{m}x.$$

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Comment: de nada. Suerte. Cualquier duda vuelves a preguntar. Sin embargo en esta comunidad debes escribir tu pregunta y además escribir lo que has intentado hacer (y decir en dónde encuentras dificultades). Generalmente a las personas de esta comunidad no les agrada responder preguntas relacionadas con tareas (a mi sí me gusta). Sin embargo evita hacer preguntas simples porque te pueden cerrar tus preguntas.