# Hooke's Law and Simple Harmonic Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

Can anyone explain how the following formula is derived and what it means?

$$x'' = -n^2x
$$
I was reading through my high school physics textbook and I stumbled upon a section on Hooke's Law. It says that $n$ is the constant in simple harmonic motion. I understand that $x''$ is acceleration and $x$ most likely refers to the extension of the spring, however, I don't really understand what is meant by the constant of SHM. How is it calculated and what does it mean?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Physics_%28Advancing_Physics%29/Simple_Harmonic_Motion

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19588/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

Compare [Hooke's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law), $F=-kx$, with [Newton's 2nd law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion), $F=ma$:
$$
m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-kx\tag{1}
$$
where $[k]=\rm N/m=kg/s^2$ and $[m]=\rm kg$. (1) can also be written as,
$$
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\frac{k}{m}x\tag{2}
$$
So $[k/m]=\rm 1/s^2$. Why not make up a *new* variable, call it $\omega$, with units of $\rm1/s$, such that (2) becomes,
$$
x''=-\omega^2x
$$
i.e., $\omega^2=k/m$; this is your constant of simple harmonic motion.

This differential equation has a known solution of the form,
$$
x(t)=A\cos(\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t)
$$
Hopefully you've seen a [sinusoidal plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) and can recognize that $\omega$ represents *the number of oscillations that occur each second of time* (quote from Wiki page).

Answer (score 1):

Hooke's law describes the force a spring exerts when its length is changed.

Of course it makes intuitive sense that when you try to change the length of a spring (by pressing it, for example) the spring exerts a force on your hand, and resists the compression.

For Hooke, this suggested that the force exerted by a spring is always in the opposite direction of the change in length of the spring - When compressed the spring pushes outwards and when pulled apart, the spring tries to compress itself back into that **equilibrium length**. The **equilibrium length** is the length of the spring when no force is exerted. Hooke conducted experiments on springs and found that the extension/compression of the spring was proportional to the force the spring exerted.
As an equation: $$ F=-kx $$

,where k was a constant Hooke calculated from the slope of his graph of F vs. x from his experimental data.

From newtons second law $ F=ma=mx'' $, we get $$ F=mx''=-kx $$
hence, $$ x''=-\frac km x $$

However, when one solves this using differential equation, one obtains $$ x(t)=A\sin ({\sqrt{\frac km}}t+\phi) $$
where $ \phi $ and $ A $ are constants determined by the initial conditions.

As you can see, if $ \frac km $ is replaced by $ n^2 $ Newtons law will turn out like it is in your textbook: $$ x''=-n^2x $$
which yields the much nicer looking $$ x(t) = A\sin (nt+\phi) $$

So as such Hookes law was not initially proved theoretically, but rather was based on experimental data
The 'constant' of SHM you cite may refer to $ n=\sqrt {\frac km} $ or to the spring constant $ k $, but the meaning of the term should be clear from the context of its usage.

Comment: $F=-n^2x$ is incorrect, as that would lead to $mx''=-n^2x$.