# Solving ODE of spring to get simple harmonic equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

$F=-kx$...(A)

$d^2x/dt^2=-kx / m $...(B)

$x=A \cos(wt -\phi)$...(C)

solve (B) to give (C), and the converse as well.

Generate (B) from (C).

I can differentiate (C) twice to give,

$a=-\omega ^2 x $

That proves the converse, although solving ODE is not I am comfortable with.

Comment: It's a linear combination of sin and cos with coefficeints fixed by the initial conditions.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19588/2451 and links therein.

Comment: guys no its not duplicate as none of them gave what i needed.

Comment: It appears duplicate only superficially because the answers needed are different. Solving ODE is hard, and the converse too

Comment: I have managed to solve the converse,but no idea on differential eqs.

Comment: Hi @Minikute. Your question appears to be, "how do I solve this ODE?" This differs from your question title. In any case, it seems to be a pure math exercise. You might consider taking a look at resources such as [this one](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Book%3A_Differential_Equations_for_Engineers_(Lebl)/2%3A_Higher_order_linear_ODEs/2.2%3A_Constant_coefficient_second_order_linear_ODEs), which explains in detail how to solve such equations. Though ODE's can be very difficult to solve, this one is quite straightforward.

Comment: @Minikute This question is a homework-like question which is off-topic for this site. However I can give you a hint: To solve a ODE of the form $\ddot{x}(t)=f(x)$, the standard method is to start by multiplying both sides by $2\dot{x}$ and integrating, which will enable you to find $\dot{x}$.