# Combination of Simple Harmonic Motions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, harmonic-oscillator, superposition

Will the combination of 2 Simple Harmonic motions will be an SHM in itself?
For example for simple functions such as

$$\ f(t)=\sin\omega t-\cos\omega t$$ I can use trigonometry to show that it can be expressed as $$\ f(t)=\sqrt 2\sin(\omega t-\pi/4) $$.

But what about functions given in the questions given below?

[Ref: “NCERT Class 11th (XI) Physics, Part 2”, Digital Designs; notes on p. 357 and Problem 14.4, p. 359 <[link](https://books.google.de/books?id=H0FiBgAAQBAJ)> ]

In (b) I can express the function as a combination of

$\sin\omega t$ and $\sin3\omega t$.

Each of these 2 terms can independently express an SHM but will their combination do the same?

[image]

As an answer to part (b) and (d) ,the book says that the superposition of two SHM is always periodic but never an SHM. (I believe that this is incorrect.Maybe a typo)

Moreover, at the end of the chapter there is a note:
[image]

I am getting pretty confused.

Can anybody tell me when the combination of **2 SHM's** be an **SHM/periodic/not periodic**?

Comment: This [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1018/76263) and the provided answers could be helpful. @Karan Singh

Comment: I think the defining property of a simple harmonic motion is that it is a _periodic_ motion with a constant amplitude and a constant phase; that is, it should be possible to describe it as $x(t) = A \, \cos(\omega t + \phi)$, where $A$, $\omega$, and $\phi$ are _time-independent_ constants. @Karan Singh

Comment: See [Fourier Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis) & read [_General motion of continuous string & Fourier Analysis_ by Frank S Crawford Jr. in Berkeley Physics: Waves](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=-RjGMfB505oC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_book_other_versions#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: It is not $\sin 3 \omega t$ but $\sin^3 \omega t$ in the textbook question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the superposition of two simple harmonic motions
\begin{equation}
x(t) = x_1(t) + x_2(t) = A_1 \cos \left( \omega_1 t + \phi_1 \right) + A_2 \cos \left( \omega_2 t + \phi_2 \right).
\end{equation}
The first motion $x_1(t)$ is periodic with period $T_1 = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_1}$ and the second motion $x_2(t)$ is periodic with period $T_2 = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_2}$. Clearly the sum of both is only periodic if $n T_1 = m T_2$ where $n$ and $m$ are positive integers (thanks to user fibonatic for pointing out the most general case). To see this, simply write 
\begin{equation}
x\left(t+nT_1\right) = x_1\left(t+nT_1\right) + x_2\left(t+mT_2\right) = x_1(t) + x_2(t) = x(t).
\end{equation}

Moreover if the period of both harmonic motions is the same $\omega_1 = \omega_2 = \omega$, we can write
\begin{align}
x(t) & = A_1 \left[ \cos(\omega t) \cos \phi_1 - \sin(\omega t) \sin \phi_1  \right] + A_2 \left[ \cos(\omega t) \cos \phi_2  - \sin(\omega t) \sin \phi_2  \right] \\
& = \left[ A_1 \cos \phi_1  + A_2 \cos \phi_2  \right] \cos(\omega t) - \left[ A_1 \sin(\phi_1) + A_2 \sin \phi_2  \right] \sin(\omega t) \\
& = A \cos \left( \omega t + \phi \right),
\end{align}
where used the sum rule $\cos\left( \alpha + \beta \right) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \alpha \sin \beta$, and we defined
\begin{align}
A \cos \phi & = A_1 \cos \phi_1  + A_2 \cos \phi_2  \\
A \sin \phi & = A_1 \sin \phi_1  + A_2 \sin \phi_2 .
\end{align}
This can be generalized to an arbitrary sum of harmonic motions with the same period:
\begin{equation}
\sum_i A_i \cos \left( \omega t + \phi_i \right) = A \cos \left( \omega t + \phi \right).
\end{equation}
Another way to understand this, is to note that the harmonic equation is a linear differential equation; any linear combination of solutions is also a solution.

**Conclusion**

The sum of two harmonic motions with frequencies $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ is periodic if the ratio $\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2}$ is a positive rational number. If the ratio is irrational, the resulting motion is not periodic.

If, moreover, the frequencies of the two harmonic motions are equal, the resulting motion is also a harmonic motion with the same frequency.

Comment: I would have to disagree with you, for example according to your definition $\omega_1=3$ and $\omega_2=5$ should not be periodic, but it is. Namely it is periodic if $\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2}=\frac{n}{m}$, where $n$ and $m$ are both positive integers.

Comment: @fibonatic Indeed, I have changed my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @KaranSingh I have updated my answer. I made an oversight concerning the periodicity. See the comment of fibonatic.