# Confusion about why sine/cos is used to represent SHM

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

When I learnt about shm 2 weeks ago I was confused why SHM $x$-$t$ relation) is represented by sine or cosine function. It is hard to imagine the motion of pendulum as a sine or cosine motion (quite impossible). As of now I learnt the whole chapter.

I answered my confusion by guessing that: - As SHM is periodic, it is represented by a sine or cosine function. Is this guess correct?

But at the end I still have a small doubt that whether it is sine/cos because it is periodic or the motion of pendulum is LITERALLY sine or cosine motion.

Comment: If you swing the pendulum really hard it rotates in a circle. This should tell you that the actual trajectory is not sin/cos but part of a circle. What is sin/cos is the angle that the pendulum makes as a function of time. 

The animation here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&ved=2ahUKEwjf9vOZwrXnAhURfSsKHSfTCeg4ChC3AjABegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D1tlxPjkBBgA&usg=AOvVaw2_us3Ejo6zcmf0FWbHLQUj might help though it is for a spring system. But this can be extended to pendulum

Comment: @user3518839 Ok, so it is the angle the pendulum makes, which kind of explains why we have π, 2π as phase constant as π and all are angles (?) . But we can also think of it as whenever pendulum reaches mean position we take 2π/4π ....etc as it is repeated, This explanation also fits the answer as why we have sine/cosine representing them.

Comment: No. Can you use this link https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104025/shm 
so we can have a private conversation? It will be cumbersome to discuss in comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explanation: Simple Harmonic Motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/explanation-simple-harmonic-motion)

Answer (score 2):

No. The motion of the pendulum is not in sine or a cosine form. Although it looks like a part of a sine or a cosine wave. The sine or cosine is written to represent the periodic motion of the pendulum and not necessarily its trajectory. The conventional equation *y=Asin(wt+kx)* (where A=amplitude, w=frequency)  is used to represent the variation in the displacement from the mean position of the pendulum bob. So, Y that is the function of sine and cosine represents the change in the displacement. Amplitude(A) which is the maximum displacement remains constant. 
refer for more info and check of the interesting animations :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)

Comment: I am aware that amplitude is maximum displacement and also that it does not vary with time. what varies is Y. I suspect a communication gap between your statement and my understanding of it. So, it will be quite helpful if you could elaborate the error.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. I have made the necessary changes. let me know if it suffices.

Comment: Yes that's ok now.

Answer (score 2):

For small angles of swing of a pendulum (where the sine of the angle of displacement from equilibrium is nearly equal to the angle in radians), the restoring torque and resulting angular acceleration are proportional to the angle.  To describe the motion you need a function of time which meets this condition.  With basic calculus, one can show that the sine or cosine functions do meet this condition.